# Use groupingBy and filtering out entire groups

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of MyObjects like this

| ID | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Summary |  |
| 1 | Detail | keep this group |
| 1 | Detail | keep this group |
| 2 | Summary |  |
| 2 | Detail | don't keep this group |
| 2 | Detail | don't keep this group |

I'd like to group the list by ID and filter out the groups that do not contain any Descriptions with "keep this group" as the value.

Below is what I have tried

```
   Map<String, List<MyObject>> output =
        myObjectList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getId,
                    Collectors.filtering(x -> x.getDescription().equals("keep this group"),
                        Collectors.toList())));
```

This does not really work thought. It creates the groups and removes all elements without "keep this group"

So group 1 has 2 elements and group 2 has 0 elements

I'd like to completely reject group 2 and keep all elements in group 1

Comment: can you filter based on description before the collect?

Comment: But that will lose the Summary records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested code.
It will remove group which does not have any object description equals "keep this group".

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> output =
 myObjectList.stream() 
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getId))
.entrySet()
.stream()
.filter(e-> e.getValue().stream().filter(o->o.getDescription().equals("keep this group")).count()>0)
.collect(Colletors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: This works. Just used anyMatch instead of count

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Collectors.collectingAndThen` should be used to filter out the groups where there is no any item in the value list:

```java
Map<String, List<MyObject>> output = myObjectList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyObject::getId,
            HashMap::new, // or pther mutable implementation of Map
            Collectors.toList()
        ), // Map<String, List<MyObject>>
        map -> { 
            map.entrySet().removeIf(
                e -> e.getValue()
                      .stream()
                      .noneMatch(obj -> "keep this group".equals(obj.getDescription()))
            );
            return map;
        }
    ));
```

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy` returns an unspecified type of a `Map`, in theory it could be an immutable one, so `removeIf` could fail.

Comment: @Eugene starting from [Java 8 implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l853), HashMap is returned for `Collectors.groupingBy` as a default implementation which is quite reasonable for collector.

Comment: right, but that is not documented as auch. This can change any time